# Rails - text_field_tag not showing up with Javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have vary basic index page with a drop down Yes/No selection. Default is No.
When Yes is selected I want to have a text input tag displayed so I can enter a reason for skipping an assessment.
If No is selected the text input field should be removed.

Here is my code:

```
<h1 id='main_header'>test-01</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Action<//th>
    <th>Skip assessment</th>
    <th>Reason for skipping</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Start asseement', controller: :home, action: :start_assessment, id: 'start_assessment' %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= select_tag "skip_option", options_for_select([ "Yes", "No" ], "No"), id: "skip_option", :onchange => "reason_picker()" %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= text_field_tag "reason_for_skipping", nil, size: 50, placeholder: 'Enter reason here...', style: "display: none;" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready (
    function reason_picker () {
      var selected = document.getElementById("skip_option").selectedIndex;
      alert(selected);
      if (selected == 0) {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").show();
        alert("if");
      }
      else {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").hide();
        alert("else");
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

I am always getting the "else" branch, selected index is always 1 and when selecting Yes from the drop down (this should be selected index 0), the text input tag is never shown.
Don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
<%= select_tag "skip_option", options_for_select([ "Yes", "No" ], "No"), id: "skip_option", :onchange => "reason_picker()" %>
```

`reason_picker()` will be undefined

To fix it, you may easily refactor your javascript like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready (
    window.reason_picker = funtion() {  # <-- change here
      var selected = document.getElementById("skip_option").selectedIndex;
      alert(selected);
      if (selected == 0) {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").show();
        alert("if");
      }
      else {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").hide();
        alert("else");
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to hide link_to when reason_for_skipping is shown and vice versa?

Comment: I attempted this, but does not work: 

      if (selected == 0) {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").show();
        $("#start_assessment").hide();
      }
      else {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").hide();
        $("#start_assessment").show();
      }
    }

Comment: because your params for `link_to` is incorrect, it should be `<%= link_to 'Start asseement', url_for(controller: :home, action: :start_assessment), id: 'start_assessment' %>`

Comment: Your version of the code worked perfect, also this version works: <%= link_to 'Start assessment', {controller: :home, action: :start_assessment}, id: 'start_assessment', style: "display: none;" %>